# Auto set height of table view based on UICollectionView inside it

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uitableview

I have a UITableView with cells that have inside a UICollectionView. 
Now all works great except of UICollectionViewCell scrolling i want that the height of table view cell follow the Collection view cell content. 
In simple word i want scrolling in table view but not inside single cell i need to display all contents of UIcollectionViewCell without scrolling inside it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to calculate the collectionviews' heights and set a height constraint on each of them. then add top and bottom constraints from the collectionviews to their superviews (the tableviewcells / their contentviews) and let autolayout do its work.

don't forget

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44 // or something similar
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

in the controller's `viewDidLoad` to make the automatic row height calculation work.